# From VMware and Fedora 29 ssh to remote machine cause Broken pipe

Tags: linux, ssh, fedora, vmware-player

I install Fedora 29 on VMware player just now, and found ssh to remote machine fails with "Broken pipe". Fedora 29 is just available few days, did you meet this problem?

```
$ ssh cranuser22@10.39.158.52
cranuser22@10.39.158.52's password:
packet_write_wait: Connection to 10.39.158.52 port 22: Broken pipe
```

And in the same VMware player, I have installed Fedora 28, it works fine.

```
$ ssh cranuser22@10.39.158.52
cranuser22@10.39.158.52's password:
Last login: Wed Oct 31 08:07:41 2018 from 10.140.176.37
```

Answer (score 15, accepted):

```
$ cat ~/.ssh/config
Host *
    IPQoS=throughput
```

After add such ssh configuration file, the problem disappears.

Update:
scp command have to use this way:

```
$ scp -o 'IPQoS=throughput' ...
```

Comment: See also this [OpenSSH 7.8 causes VMware Workstation and Player networking SSH bug on Linux VMs](https://github.com/vmware/open-vm-tools/issues/287) on github

Comment: Never thought that it could be a problem of VMWare. In my case VMWare Fusion.

Answer (score 0):

just for additional, i also got that log in my VM, my case appear because there are 2 VM that have same networking configuration (IP Adress), i think we are in the same case, please make sure to change your netowrk configuration with different ip address, and start to ssh again to your VM.

Cheers,